# PowerShell v5 UTF8 format lost after conversion CR LF to LF

Tags: vba, powershell, encoding, utf-8

I'm using a vba macro to write a PS1 script in order to :

- first convert my txt file to UTF8 format
- Second, convert CR LF to LF.

But when I do so, i'm loosing the UTF8 format.

Here is my code :

```
$file = 'C:\Users\c92434\Downloads\run_param_21_04_21\dg_poc_parameter.txt'
(Get-Content $file) | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 $file
((Get-Content $file) -join "`n") + "`n" | Set-Content -NoNewline $file
```

Best regards,

Jouvzer

Comment: Consider `Get-Content -Encoding` and `Set-Content -Encoding`

Comment: for wich line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in one go:

```
$file = 'C:\Users\c92434\Downloads\run_param_21_04_21\dg_poc_parameter.txt'
(Get-Content -Path $file -Raw) -replace '\r?\n', "`n" | Set-Content -Path $file -NoNewline -Encoding UTF8
```

The `-Raw` switch on Get-Content reads the file as one single, multilined string.
The `` -replace '\r?\n', "`n" `` replaces all CRLF into LF